# android:textColorHighlight=transparent is being ignored

Tags: android, textview

I have TextView. some of the text has ClickableSpan.
once the text is being clicked, it gets highlighted.

When I put this line in the TextView xml
`android:textColorHighlight="@color/red"`
the highlight will be red, as expected.

The thing is that i don not want it to be highlighted and
`android:textColorHighlight="@color/transparent"`
doesn't work.

any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Try `android:background="#07000000"` or in your class `setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);` also you can add an Alpha `android:alpha="0.2"`

Comment: What was that error?

Comment: Anyways I gave you some ideas, maybe if you face with more issues you can try them out.

Comment: the solution was to write in the code: textview.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);  the reason is that I had ClickableSpan so I had to write textview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()); and it did all the trouble..  Thanks to you all

Answer (score 1):

Try `android:background="#07000000"`

In your java.class `setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

Also you can add an Alpha `android:alpha="0.2"`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the internal `TextView.applyTextAppearance` method has the following code:

```
    if (attributes.mTextColorHighlight != 0) {
        setHighlightColor(attributes.mTextColorHighlight);
    }
```

I would say that is a bug because this invalidates the #00000000 color from being used, which translate to 0.

To fix your issue, you shouldn't use #00000000 but rather other full transparent color such as #00FFFFFF.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with:

```
android:textColorHighlight="@null"
```

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/transparent"
```